# JTextPane and newlines

Tags: java, linux, swing, newline, jtextpane

I'm writing a program that (at one point) makes a command-line call to another native application, gets the output from that application, and puts it into a JTextPane as a String. The problem is, it doesn't seem to grab the newline characters the way it should. Because I'm using linux, each line ends with a `^M` instead of a `\n`.

Is there any way to tell Java to look for those and create a newline in the string?

```
private void getSettings() {
    Commander cmd = new Commander();
    settings = cmd.getCommandOutput("hdhomerun_config " + ipAddress + " get /sys/boot");
    settingsTextPane.setText(settings);
}
```

I end up with the output barfed into one line and wrapped around in the text pane.

Comment: Have you tried the linux equivalent for /r/n  or  line.separator property ?

Comment: BTW - Why use `JTextPane` for plain text?  `JTextArea` is simpler..

Comment: search for System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I looked through my code again and realized I was reading the output from the program one line at a time, and just appending the lines. I needed to add a \n at the end of each line that I read. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Java automatically corrects newlines based on your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall Unix displays `^M` for the carriage return character `\r` so you could try to replace it by using the [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method of the String class

```
settingsTextPane.setText(settings.replace('\r', '\n'));
```